# Execution failed: 'app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED' -ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-native

I have installed react-native-navigation locally inside the project, even then it is displaying an error app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED. I then tried cd android and then ran gradlew clean, however the error persists
 Please check the Full error:

```
 Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
302 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 301 up-to-date
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:2: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
                                ^
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class NavigationActivity
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   method getMainComponentName()
  location: class MainActivity
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:20: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to Context
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
                                                                       ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:2: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
                                ^
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class NavigationActivity
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   method getMainComponentName()
  location: class MainActivity
C:\Users\User\Baaz\android\app\src\main\java\com\baaz\MainActivity.java:20: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to Context
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
                                                                       ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\User\Baaz\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\User\Baaz\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at C:\Users\User\Baaz\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\User\Baaz\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

The following is the main mainactivvity.java file

MainActivity.java

```
package com.baaz;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.baaz;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.baaz.generated.BasePackageList;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList(),
    Arrays.<SingletonModule>asList()
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new ReanimatedPackage(),
          new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
          new RNScreensPackage(),
          new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "postinstall": "jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "~0.61.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^4.5.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.7.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "~24.9.0",
    "jest": "~24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "~1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "~0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Kindly, answer and do let me know if anything else is equired to solve this error

Comment: have you followed complete installation steps https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing

Comment: @Revansiddh Thank you so much, have done it accordingly again but yet am continuing to get the error, however I realized that I should run npm run android, but when I did so I got the following error:

Comment: > @ android C:\Users\User\Baaz
> cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ android: `cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug`

Comment: try using taking build by command `npx react-native run-android
` instead of npm run android

Comment: can i know your react native version...

Comment: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.        This is the erroe coming still @Revansiddh

Comment: 0.61.5 is my react native version, react-native-cli->2.0.1   @SavinderSingh

Comment: so i think your android project MainActivity.java and MainApplication.java files run in previous version of react native, so you should have to upgrade your project follow this link  :->  https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/   Here you have to set your previous version of project and newest version in which you want to update.Please follow instructions carefully, it will help you to upgrade project and hope everything would be work. After you update your code you dont have need to update code manually. It would be so simple.

Comment: How does upgrading my react-native version help upgrading mainapplication and mainactivity? Am a newbie in react-native hence curious to know @SavinderSingh

Comment: After upgrade, you dont have to manually or via command link libraries. It can handle automatically link libraries. it also reduces your code. You also have to update your  mainapplication and mainactivity files in react native latest version.

Comment: You can check in this link react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper, It's easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by running:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: can you explain what this does ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED at the same issue:

My solution was at /android/build.gradle file.
Somehow, the buildscript versions were wrong.

Follow the exact same step of RN documentation and make a totally new & clean project.
And compate the /android/build.gradle file > buildscript & dependencies part.
There should be some version differences.
It matters by your own local env settings.

After changing buildToolsVersion, ndkVersion, classpath, it worked fine again!!